# Do not show options in selectbox after max options using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$( "#multipleOptions" ).change(function() {
    if (this.selectedOptions.length <= 3) {
        var multipleOptions = [0];
        if ($(this).val()){
            multipleOptions = $(this).val();
        }
        var postData = { "multipleOptions": multipleOptions }
        $.ajax(url = "/app/"+multipleOptionsId+"/",
            type="PATCH",
            data=postData,
            success=function(resp){
                notify("Multiple Options update was successful", "success");
            },
            error=function(){
                alert("Could not save", "error");
            }
        );
    } else {
        alert("You can only select a maximum of three options");
    }
});
```

Here I need to limit the number of options to three. Now from what I have written it does not send options more than three to the backend but the problem is that it will show extra options when selected in the selectbox along with the alert message if there are more than three options. How can I not show the extra option and only the alert message?

Comment: `change` occurs *after* the values have changed, so you can't cancel them.  You can instead "store" the current values when `<=3` then when `>3` restore those values

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @freedomn-m 's comment, this is how I got it working:

```
var multipleOptionsVar;

$( "#multipleOptions" ).change(function() {
    if (this.selectedOptions.length <= 3) {
        var multipleOptions = [0];
        if ($(this).val()){
            multipleOptions = $(this).val();
            multipleOptionsVar = multipleOptions;
        }
        var postData = { "multipleOptions": multipleOptions }
        $.ajax(url = "/app/"+multipleOptionsId+"/",
            type="PATCH",
            data=postData,
            success=function(resp){
                notify("Multiple Options update was successful", "success");
            },
            error=function(){
                alert("Could not save", "error");
            }
        );
    } else {
        $(this).val(multipleOptionsVar);
        $(this).trigger("change.select2");
        alert("You can only select a maximum of three options");
    }
});

window.onload = function(e) {
    multipleOptionsVar = $( "#multipleOptions" ).val();
}
```