# how to cancel change event on conformation in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button, checkbox

This is Gajarthan, I am new to jQuery. I try to prevent a Check box from being changed if not confirmed by the user. but it's not working when I click the first time. after 2nd click, it's working properly.

this is the summary of my function

> when I click the toggle button it needs to show a confirmation alert "Are you sure you want to proceed?" then if I click yes. if toggle inactive it needs to change active.  if toggle active it needs to change inactive. and if I click no. toggle won't change!

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.toggle-class').change(function() {
                var value =  $(this).prop('checked');
                var proceed = confirm("Are you sure you want to proceed?");
                if (proceed) {
                    console.log(value);
                }
                else{
                    $(this).prop('checked' ,!value);
                }

            })
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<input class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="InActive" >
```

Comment: The `change` event fires only after the checked status has _already_ changed, so you would need to set this back to the previous one then, if the user does not want to proceed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do not show options in selectbox after max options using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66797887/do-not-show-options-in-selectbox-after-max-options-using-jquery)

Comment: The above linked answer is clearly a different question, but the principle is the same:  record the value before the change, the restore it if it's not wanted.

Comment: An alternative would be to *hide* the "checkbox" and have a `<button>` that the user clicks which updates the checkbox after confirmation - ie a small change to the UI to make your life much easier.  You could even make the button *look like* a checkbox but not *be* an `<input type="checkbox"`, if that's an issue.

Comment: I am sorry guys. actually, this is not my problem. now I updated my question please check.

Comment: anyone can answer me?